# Join 8 mono channels into 7.1 audio stream

Tags: ffmpeg, channel

I'm trying to join 8 mono channels into 7.1 channels layout:

```
ffmpeg -i L.ac3 -i R.ac3 -i C.ac3 -i Sub.ac3 -i BL.ac3 -i BR.ac3 -i SL.ac3 -i SR.ac3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a][6:a][7:a]join=inputs=8:channel_layout=7.1[a]"
-map "[a]" final-output.ac3
```

but I'm getting:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (ac3) -> join:input0
  Stream #1:0 (ac3) -> join:input1
  Stream #2:0 (ac3) -> join:input2
  Stream #3:0 (ac3) -> join:input3
  Stream #4:0 (ac3) -> join:input4
  Stream #5:0 (ac3) -> join:input5
  Stream #6:0 (ac3) -> join:input6
  Stream #7:0 (ac3) -> join:input7
  join -> Stream #0:0 (ac3)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, ac3, to 'final-output.ac3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, **5.1(side)**, fltp, 640 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 ac3
```

Why the output file is 5.1(side) ?

```
Audio
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Commercial name                          : Dolby Digital
Duration                                 : 54 min 5 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 640 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : L R C LFE Ls Rs
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 248 MiB (100%)
Service kind                             : Complete Main
```

I did not found anything that would explain this behavior.
I'm using latest ffmpeg and tried different methods: join, amerge. Always output file is 5.1(side)

Comment: ffmpeg's AC-3 encoder only supports upto 6 channels.

Comment: See `ffmpeg -h encoder=ac3` to view supported channel layouts.

Comment: Yes, supported channel layouts for ac3 are:     mono stereo 3.0(back) 3.0 quad(side) quad 4.0 5.0(side) 5.0 2 channels (FC+LFE) 2.1 4 channels (FL+FR+LFE+BC) 3.1 5 channels (FL+FR+LFE+SL+SR) 5 channels (FL+FR+LFE+BL+BR) 4.1 5.1(side) 5.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          That means no way to replace central mono channel in 7.1 stream with another one from another stream.